# How to write a function that takes in int parameters and print them out in combination? Eg: 1,2,3,4 -> 1234

Tags: c#, function

I'm just learning how to code in C#. For homework assignment, we were required to write a method that takes in 8 different `int` values and returns another `int` with all the values combined. `(1, 2, 3, 4)` becomes `1234` for example. The method will then return the output to the `Main` function to print out with `Console.WriteLine`. Just confused as to what I'm supposed to do because I can't return a string when the method is an `int`, and adding all the `int`s together just adds up all the numbers.

The method:

```
static int CombineNumbers(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h) {
  return();
}
```

is supposed to read the int values from `Main`:

```
Console.WriteLine(CombineNumbers(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8));
```

Comment: 1. Convert all numeric values to `string` using `ToString()` 2. Concatenate all `string` values to create a single `string` 3. Convert single `string` back to `int` using `Int32.TryParse()`.

Comment: Or use `string output =  $"{a}{b}{c}{d}";`

Comment: Wait, have we all forgotten to use simple math? a * 10000000 + b * 1000000 + c * 100000 .....

Comment: Yeap, Steve is correct on that front. We were only supposed to write the method using bare basics C#. I overcomplicated things myself by thinking it needed some advanced programming. Figured that out shortly after I've posted this. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `Join` and `params`.

Create a method to take a `params` of int array (so you are not restricted to specific size of parameter) and than join it. if you want just to return the number joined together as string do as follow:

```
public static string CombineNumbers1(params int[] arr)
{
    return string.Join("", arr);
}
```

if you want to return a integer type of the numbers you can Convert or Parse it as follows:

```
public static int CombineNumbers2(params int[] arr)
{
    int.TryParse(string.Join("", arr), out int val);
    return val;
}
```

So when I pass following to method:

CombineNumbers1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

It should returns

12345678 as string in first method and as integer in second method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the numbers as strings and then convert the string to an int again:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CombineNumbers(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8));
    }

    static int CombineNumbers(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h) {
        String resultString = a.ToString() + b.ToString() + c.ToString() + d.ToString() + e.ToString() + f.ToString() + g.ToString() + h.ToString();
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(resultString);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function can helps you, you can increase number of parameters easily.

```
public class Program
{
        public static void Main()
        {
          Console.WriteLine(MyFunc(1, 2, 3, 4));
        }


        private int MyFunc(int a, int b, int c, int d)
        {
            var str = new List<int>() { a, b, c, d};

           return str.Aggregate((x, y) => int.Parse(x.ToString() + y.ToString()));
        }
}
```